# RegEx minimum 4 characters with no repetition

Tags: regex

Trying to create a regex where a field should contain minimum 4 characters(only alphabets [a-zA-Z]) where

1. first 4 alphabets should not repeat. eg aaaa,zzzz not acceptable
2. first 4 characters should not contain space, numbers, special characters
3. afterwhich anything is fine

I tried following expression but 1 case is failing which is (a123,a@#!):
^(?=.{1,4}$)(([a-zA-Z]){1,4}\2?(?!\2))+[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&()\-`.+,"]

Comment: Maybe `^(?![a-zA-Z]{0,2}([a-zA-Z])\1)[a-zA-Z]{1,4}.*` will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write the pattern as:

```
^(?!(.)\1{3})[a-zA-Z]{4}.*
```

**Explanantion**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!(.)\1{3})` Negative lookahead, assert not 4 of the same characters
- `[a-zA-Z]{4}` Match 4 chars a-z A-Z
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AG6Xhj/1)